# Problems updating MySql DB with 20.000 records

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook

I am trying to launch one php process that should read about 20.000 records, call facebook API, return some data and update the database.

But after 500 or so records, the page timeouts and says:

```
""Network Error (tcp_error)
A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
For assistance, contact your network support team. ""
```

I think that maybe is because there are lot's of connections IN and OUT from this server so the server stops responding.

Also, if I try to open any page on the same domain, I can't. The page is hanging utill the process finish.

Is there anything that can be optimized?

Comment: @Silver Light, @Sourav, thanks for the sugestion. I will try to "sleep" between the calls.

But what about the second problem. 
Even if I update 100 records, I can't open anything on the same domain untill the process finish? This is a problem as there are users all the time.

Comment: are you using file-based sessions? PHP locks the session file while a script is actively using it. If your processing script isn't modifying the session while doing this long batch job, do a `session_write_close()` to free up the session so you can use other parts of the site that also use sessions. otherwise your script will "lock you out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that facebook might have limit on connections in a period of time. I suggest you cplit your script in chunks and process 400 records at a time. Put a `sleep()` between chunks or, better, make separate script calls.